# Not able to draw properly on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

```
<Window x:Class="ShelfMapping.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Shelf Mapping" Height="1080" Width="1920"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded" Unloaded="Window_Unloaded">
    <Grid>

        <Image Name="camera" />
        <Image Name="depthOut"/>
        <Canvas Name="canvas"/>

        <Grid Style="{StaticResource GridButtonsStyle}">
            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource StackPanelButtonsStyle}">
                <Button Content="Screenshot" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="buttonScreenshotClick" />
                <Button Content="OCR" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="click_OCR" />
                <Button Content="Back to stream" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Click="click_backToStream" />
                <TextBox Name="txtCode" Height="50" Width="150"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is my XAML file.

[image: This is the image of the points and rectangles drawn on canvas]

```
Ellipse ellipse = new Ellipse();
                ellipse.Width = 20;
                ellipse.Height = 20;

                SolidColorBrush blueBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                blueBrush.Color = Colors.Blue;
                SolidColorBrush redBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                redBrush.Color = Colors.DarkRed;

                // Set Ellipse's width and color
                ellipse.StrokeThickness = 4;
                ellipse.Stroke = redBrush;
                // Fill rectangle with blue color
                ellipse.Fill = blueBrush;

                Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, infoInt[0] - ellipse.Width / 2);
                Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, infoInt[1] - ellipse.Height / 2);

                canvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
```

This is where I'm drawing points.The output of the points are correct according to the image pixels put it is drawing somewhere else in the canvas. The ellipse should be drawn exactly on the number, but it is drawing somewhere else. I dont know how to fix it. Help me out of this.

Comment: I think it depends on infoInt[0] and infoInt[1].   Can you show the code where these are set?

Comment: `Image` may scale source image (by default [`Image.Stretch="Uniform"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx)). Try to add some visual on top of `Grid` at expected coordinates (using `Margin`), to see if it's `Image` or `Canvas` problem.

Comment: infoInt[0] and infoInt[1] corectly points to the numbers.. but it is drawing somewhere else.. @JamesHarcourt

Comment: @Sinatr those rectangles are hardcoded.. Those are also drawing somewhere else

Comment: Does Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, 0); Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, 0); draw in the upper left corner?

Comment: Got it.. myy screen resolution is just 1366*768.. So while displaying 1920*1080 the problem occurs. So did scalin